# PartialView in View post and return response json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My PartialView is render in View, then this PartialView need post controller, and catch response, and show. How do that?

View

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="partialViewContainer"></div>
    </div>
```

PartialView

```
@model foo

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "ManageFiles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Some Html
    <div id="ResponsePost">
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile(UploadFileViewModel m)
{        
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorList = (from item in ModelState
                             where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                             select item.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage).ToList();

                    return Json(errorList);
            }

            //Some Logic             
            var foo = new { ... };
            return Json(foo);
}
```

Comment: Sorry ! i still do not understand what your question is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, in short words, how update partial view from jsonresult

Comment: you have to use ajax to submit your form and in your ajax success callback, udpate teh DOM as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in my opinion is by using the `Ajax.BeginForm` extension instead of `Html.BeginForm`. Less code, and easily readable.

The tradeoff is you will need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` along with Jquery.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile","ManageFiles" , new AjaxOptions() {  OnSuccess = "getResult" }))
```

Here, `getResult` is used to define the JavaScript function which will fire after the successful Ajax request.

Then you can write something like:

```
function getResult(data){
    $('#ResponsePost').append('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ajax to submit your data and when your action method returns the JSON respose, udpate the DOM as needed. You need to use `FormData` to send the file and other input fields in the form.

Assuming your partial view rendered a form with Id `replaceYourFormIdHere` which has an input file element with Id `Img`

```
$("#replaceYourFormIdHere").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formAction = $(this).attr("action");

    var fdata = new FormData();

    var fileInput = $('#Img')[0];
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    fdata.append("Img", file);

    // You can update the jquery selector to use a css class if you want
    $("input[type='text'").each(function (x, y) {
        fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: formAction,
        type: "POST",
        data: fdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var msg = "<ul>";
            if (data.status === "success") {
                msg += '<li>' + data.message + '</li>';;
            } else {
                $.each(data.errorList,
                    function(a, b) {
                        msg+= '<li>' + b + '</li>';
                    });
            }
            msg += "</ul>";
            $("#ResponsePost").html(msg);
        },
        error: function(x, y, z) {
            alert('error al postear');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Assuming your action method returns a JSON response with a status property.

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //to do : Save model.Img
        return Json(new {status = "success", message = "Success!"});
    }
    else
    {
        var errorList = (from modelStateVal in ViewData.ModelState.Values from error 
                            in modelStateVal.Errors select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return Json(new { status = "error", errorList = errorList });
    }
}
```

Assuming your `UploadFileViewModel`  has a `Img` property of type `HttpPostedFileBase`

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Img { set; get; }
```

Make sure that you are not putting the script in the partial view. It is best to include the script in the main view.

Comment: That means your ajax code is failing. It could be because of a script error in your page. Check your browser dev tools->console to see any possible errors. Also you can put a `console.log` inside your `success` callback for debugging.